# Compute $\sum_{k=4}^{n=30} \frac{C(25,k-3) * 4^{2k-7}}{k-2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

Compute $\sum_{k=4}^{n=30} \frac{C(25,k-3) * 4^{2k-7}}{k-2}$

I started by saying $t = k-3$, so $k=t+3$
then I got 4$\sum_{k=1}^{n=27} C(25,t) * \frac{4^t}{t+1}$ and then

$\sum_{k=4}^{n=27} C(27,t) * \frac{4^t}{(t+1)26*27}$

and now I'm stuck getting rid of $1/(t+1)$, if it was $(t+1)$ I could differntiate and solve it, I believe. but if i learned how to integrate than I believe I would know how to get rid of $1/(t+1)$ , and we just started studing integrals in calculus so I'm pretty weak in that part.

What do you guys think?

Comment: If you're somehow rewriting the index $k$ in terms of $t,$ then after the rewrite there should only be the index $t$ in the sum. But you left the $k$ in it (in the range of the sum). Don't know if fixing that would help, though. [I also don't see how the constant 25 in the combination became a 27 in the last version.

Comment: I wrote here mistakenly, it is from t = 1. And about the $27$, yes i did a mistake there. But i believe i have to get somehow to 27 @coffeemath

Comment: In the original sum, before your re-expression, when $k$ reaches $30$ we have $k-3=27,$ so that $C(25,k-3)$ would read $C(25,27).$ Since that seems peculiar, maybe the 25 in the original should be 27, since then $C(27,27)=1$ would at least make sense as appearing in the last term of the sum. Please re-check the source of the problem about this, as it would make quite a difference.

Comment: C(25,k-3) = 25! / (k-3)! * (25-k+3)!. You write vice versa.

Comment: Your original sum goes from $k=4$ to $k=25$ in the title of the post. So that is OK. What confused me was you forgot to replace $k$ by $t+3$ in the limits of your summations in the body of the post. I'll look again at it later today, seems your last version makes sense if its index is replaced by $t$

Comment: It goes until k=30. My bad in the title.

Comment: I solved it. @coffeemath

Answer (score 0):

I get to:
$(0.25\sum_{t=0}^{n=25} \frac{C(25,t) * 16^{t}}{1+t}) -0.25$

and from here I use binom's formula and write $(1+x)^n$, integrate it and the equivalent binom's formula and get to the final answer:
$(0.25 * 17^{26} / 26) -0.25$